# $L_1(\phi)\subset L_\infty(\mu)$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $X=\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathcal{X}=\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ with measures: $\mu (A)=\sum_{n\in A} (1/n^3)$ and $\phi(A)=\sum_{n\in A}\frac{1}{n}$.

is it true that :

$L_1(\phi)\subset L_\infty(\mu)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Choose

$$f(n) := \begin{cases}
k, & n=2^{k}\text{ for some }k\in\mathbb{N},\\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Then $\Vert f \Vert_{L^1(\phi)} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{k}{2^k}< \infty$, but $f$ is not bounded and hence $f \notin L^{\infty}(\mu)$ (note that $\mu$ has no null sets except for $\emptyset$).